# Tortoise SVN why does it ask me to choose one if they are both the same?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I am new to Tortoise SVN

(I am actually new to version control in general but trying to fix that!)

I am playing around trying to get used to it.

I have a conflict between 2 files:

Mine

```
A

C
```

Theirs

```
A
B
```

Obviously line 2 and line 3 are different on each so they need to be resolved. But line 1 is the same on both, so why is it asking me which to use?

[image]

Comment: I don't really follow the question? The file has conflicts so they need to be resolved and you understand that. So what is the problem?

Comment: @th3dude I am just trying to understand why it is asking me which to use for line 1. If I use *mine* or if I use *theirs*, either way it is "A". Maybe that is just the way TSVN is, but I thought maybe I was missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you were [not running a Subversion server](https://superuser.com/questions/226623/setup-version-control-on-dreamweaver).