# Setup Version Control on Dreamweaver

Tags: svn, version-control, dreamweaver

I have a win computer on the Network called WIN2K8FS1

I have TortoiseSVN on a win computer and when I go to checkout a repository with Tortoise it asks me for the URL of the repository. I put in:

> file://WIN2K8FS1/Media/SVN_repo

And it creates the working copy.

---

I am trying to setup Dreamweaver CS5 to work with subversion. I create a new site and I go to the Version Control tab and it asks for a lot if info.

1. First is **Access**. I choose Subversion
   since that is the only option
2. Second is **Protocol**. Not sure which I
   need so I go with HTTP?
3. Third is **Server Address**. I am
   assuming this is the name of the
   computer with the repository so I
   put in `\\WIN2K8FS1\`
4. Fourth is **Repository Path**. I put in
   `/Media/SVN_repo`
5. Fifth is **Port** which I leave default
   to 80
6. Then it asks for user name and
   password. I never set one up for
   anything so I put in my domain
   username and password.

I click test and it tells me:

> Server and project are not accessible!

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am not the server admin but I did create the repository and have access to it via Tortoise. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong in Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is not a Subversion server - it's just a client.  You need to have a Subversion server to connect to with Dreamweaver.  If you are using Windows, [VisualSVN Standard Edition](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) is free to use.  If you do not have a separate machine to use as a server, you can use a virtual machine.  You may be able to run the server on the same machine, but I have never tried it, and it's not really the way it is intended to be used.